# Non greedy LookAhead

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I have strings like follows:

```
val:key
```

I can capture 'val' with `/^\w*/`.

How can I now get 'key' *without* the ':' sign?

Thanks

Comment: depending on your language used, there should be some sort of split() command to split strings. Just split on ":" , then get the last element. No need regex.

Comment: i was missing the simplest solution! by the way, the key may contain ':'.

Comment: So you only want it to split on the first colon? Use a chunk limit: `split(/:/, $text, 2)`

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
/^(\w+):(\w+)$/
```

Or if you just want to capture everything after the colon:

```
/:(.+)/
```

Here's a less clear example using a lookbehind assertion to ensure a colon occurred before the match - the entire match will not include that colon.

```
/(?<=:).*/
```

Comment: i'd like to capture it with a different regex and /\:(.*)/ still captures the ':'

Comment: but the parentheses will let you extract the submatch

Answer (score 1):

What language are you using?  /:(.*)/ doesn't *capture* the ":" but it does *match* the ':'

In Perl, if you say:

```
$text =~ /\:(.*)/;
$capture = $1;
$match = $&;
```

Then $capture won't have the ":" and $match will.  (But try to avoid using $& as it slows down Perl: this was just to illustrate the match).

Answer (score 1):

This will capture the key in group 1 and the value in group 2. It should work correctly even when the value contails a colon (:) character.

```
^(\w+?):(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/\:(\w*)/
```

That looks for : and then captures all the word characters after it till the end of the string